# Insert HTML tag dynamically within td to cover text

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a table.It has 2 td and 5 tr.In one td, it has a text.I want to cover that with Input Tag when I click the button.
My leader told me only table name and that td id .
And I can't insert onclick event in html inline..

So,How Can I control for that Click? and How can I insert HTML td tag dynamically to cover text?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function editTd() 
{
    var rows = document.getElementById('control');

    var input = document.createElement('input');
    input.type = "text";
    input.name="copytext";

    rows.appendChild(input);
}

window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementsByName("submitConfirm").onclick = editTd;
};
</script>
```

That's my prepared Code now. Pls help me

Comment: post your html or create a fiddle

Comment: what do you mean by cover text, the value of input should be that ?

Comment: there is a text in td but he want to cover that text with disable Input tag when button click .

Comment: means you want something like this `<input type="text" value="TEXT IN TD" disabled`. am I right?

Comment: @Ivory, do mean that text in td will be replaced by input[type=text] with the value = td.text ?

Comment: @Ivory, and what about the edit button will it change to `done`, and what after user enters some text into it.

Comment: that's why I want to make that disabled

Comment: I've added answer according what you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you

```
function editTd() {
    var rows = document.getElementById('tbl1').rows; //get all rows of that table
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {   
        var row = rows[i];   
        for (var j = 0; j < row.cells.length; j++) {  // for evary row get each cell
            var input = document.createElement('input'); //create a input text
            input.type='text';
            input.value= row.cells[j].textContent;
            input.disabled = true; //disabled input
            row.cells[j].innerHTML = '';   // clear all cell's data
            row.cells[j].appendChild(input); // append input tag to cell
        };
    };
}

window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementsByName("submitConfirm")[0].onclick = editTd;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this example, I have made some updates in it:

EDIT:

```
document.getElementById("submitConfirm").onclick = function (e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var btn = e.srcElement || e.target;
    btn.disabled = true;
    var td = document.getElementById('control');
    var bx = '<input type=\'text\' name=\'copytext\' readonly=\'readonly\' value=\'' + td.innerHTML + '\'/>';
    td.innerHTML = bx;
};
```

Comment: that answer was different from my question

Comment: @Ivory, please tell me what am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that it's best way, but try this:

```
document.getElementById('tdID').onclick = function(e){
    if(e.target.nodeName == 'TD'){
        console.log('dfdfdf');
        this.innerHTML = '<input type="text" value="' + this.innerText + '"/>'
    }
}
```

where 'tdID' - is id of td with text.

here is jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/weeklyTea/L83CX/

Comment: You need to HTML encode value to prevent XSS attack

Answer (score 0):

please have a look ... this worked for me

```
document.getElementById("submitConfirm").onclick = function (e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var btn = e.srcElement || e.target;
    btn.disabled = true;
    var td = document.getElementById('control');
    var bx = '<input type=\'text\' id="txtbx" value=\'' + td.innerHTML + '\'/>';
    td.innerHTML = bx;
    document.getElementById('txtbx').disabled=true;
};
```